# OpenSSL Custom Memory BIO for a sockets library

Tags: openssl

I'm using a transport library that emulates Berkeley sockets API for working with it (complete with blocking and non-blocking modes). Needed to add TLS encryption to the data that I'm sending and can think of two ways:

1. Custom BIO: Found code for the Socket BIO, so thinking of making a copy of it and replacing all berkeley socket calls with the functions for that library. However, I can't find much info about Custom BIOs online, so wary of pitfalls I'd run into without getting much help.
2. Memory BIO: This approach has more followers and quite a few examples as well. Although, most warn that Memory BIO with non-blocking sockets is an order of magnitude more complicated than blocking route.

Regarding Memory BIO approach, The source code that I saw made sense to me but it was a simple echo client/server. The thing that's confusing me a lot is what to do when SSL_Read/SSL_Write return SSL_WANT_READ or SSL_WANT_WRITE. My understanding is that in case of Blocking Socket BIO, you just retry the call later, since underlying code will take care of things.

In case of Memory BIO + non-blocking sockets e.g. if SSL_Read returns SSL_WANT_WRITE, does that mean that my code should then read from output BIO (BIO_read) and send it to the socket and also don't allow any SSL_Read/SSL_Write until the original SSL_Read call succeeds? is it ok to allow SSL_Write during this time?

EDIT: I'll be using TLS 1.3 exclusively, just found out that it does Not support renegotiation. Does it mean that once connection is established I don't have to worry about WANT_WRITE on SSL_Read and WANT_READ on SSL_Write at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"In case of Memory BIO + non-blocking sockets e.g. if SSL_Read returns SSL_WANT_WRITE, does that mean that my code should then read from output BIO (BIO_read) and send it to the socket"*   -- Yes.  Take all the bytes in the output BIO and write them to the socket.

It's explained [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_error.html)  why this can happen:

> Any TLS/SSL I/O function can lead to either of SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ and
>   SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE. In particular, SSL_read_ex(), SSL_read(),
>   SSL_peek_ex(), or SSL_peek() may want to write data and SSL_write() or
>   SSL_write_ex() may want to read data. This is mainly because TLS/SSL
>   handshakes may occur at any time during the protocol (initiated by
>   either the client or the server); SSL_read_ex(), SSL_read(),
>   SSL_peek_ex(), SSL_peek(), SSL_write_ex(), and SSL_write() will handle
>   any pending handshakes.

Once the SSL_read has failed in this manner, I don't think further attempt at SSL_read will succeed until you have written more bytes into the input bio.

Meanwhile you can make further attempts at SSL_write; just inspect the return code and SSL status to check whether the data was partially of fully transferred in.

I have some example code written on [github](https://github.com/darrenjs/openssl_examples)

Comment: Has your code being thoroughly tested for bugs? It looks relatively straightforward than I was expecting. E.g. in do_encrypt, if SSL_Write returns WANT_READ, then there is no case to handle that scenario and loop will immediately retry SSL_Write again. Is that correct?

Comment: Well this is example code, not guaranteeing no bugs or fully correct (although I have been using variant of it for couple years in prod).  If SSL_write was not successful (eg WANT_READ), then function returns back into select/poll loop. See here, *When using a non-blocking socket, nothing is to be done, but select() can be used to check for the required condition.* [https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_write.html]

Comment: I just added a note to my question, basically, I'll be working with TLS 1.3 exclusively, so I don't think I need to worry about WANT_WRITE & WANT_READ once a connection has been established.
Related question: OpenSSL doc says that SSL_Read will return a TLS record. Does it mean that data in each SSL_Write is treated as a separate record (message) and SSL_Read will keep asking for data until it is able to assemble that complete record(message)?

Comment: Interesting point about TLS 1.3. For SSL_read, seems to be yes according to docs, its "based on the SSL/TLS records ... only when a record has been completely received, it can be processed".  As for SSL_write, I think that single calls can generate multiple records.

Comment: Is it ok to call SSL_read and SSL_write simultaneously from two different threads? e.g. if SSL_read is blocked (blocking socket) waiting for data, would it be ok for another thread to call SSL_write?

Comment: see here -->  https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/02/21/threads/  ... there doesn't appear a conclusive summary, so I would err on the side of caution and avoid it.   This has also been asked couple times on SO.